# SSRS not updating when deploying updates from Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, charts, bids, ssrs-2014

I have updated the chart labels in Visual Studio, all works well in Preview and when I deploy the update report to SSRS, the changes isn't showing? Is there a way I can update the report without having to recreate a whole new dashboard? There must be a way I can refresh the chart in SSRS?

I would appreciate any help or suggestions I can get.

Thankyou

Comment: Usually this is due to browser caching. You may have to clear your browsing history. Caching may have been enabled on your report - check the Caching and Snapshot settings.

Comment: Hi Hannover, thanks so much for the suggestion. I did try to clear out the caching in the report and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So after numerous attempts and reading similar questions. I found a way to deploy the updated charts in SSRS from visual studio. I've basically deleted the shared datasets from Visual Studio (both in report data and solution explorer pane). I've also deleted the shared dataset and report in SSRS and redeployed. All seems to work then.